# Ros subscriber is processing an old message

Tags: c++, ros, publisher, subscriber

I am currently trying to pass some information between two ros node. 
The publisher, being a ros node written in python publishes a string on to a topic, and the subscriber, being a ros node written in cpp, has a callback function which reacts on messages being sent to that topic.

My problem is with the callback function in the cpp part, which doesn't process the recently published message, but only the one sent just before the new one.The cpp subscriber is basically one message behind.

Echoing the topic shows that the message being published on to the topic is the correct one, so something is must be wrong on the cpp part. 
The callback is currently only printing the incomming message, and nothing else.

The subscriber on the CPP part is initialized as such:

```
status(nodehandle.subscribe("/status",10000,&wrapper::callback, this))

void wrapper::callback(const std_msgs::String& command)
{
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("RECEIVED a callback");
    std::cout <<"Received unconverted message: "<< command.data << std::endl;
}
```

I tried changing the queue_size with no effect.

I am sure that the python code is publishing the right message, by debugging it via echoing the topic.

And sending multiple messages, proves that the messages received on the cpp part is delayed by one message.

Why am I not able to read the newest message published on to the topic?

MWE:

```
ros::NodeHandle nodehandle;
ros::Publisher control_cpp_to_python;
ros::Publisher control_front_to_python;
ros::Subscriber status_manual;
ros::Subscriber status_auto;
ros::Rate loop_rate;
void callback_manual(const std_msgs::String& command)
{
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("RECEIVED a callback");
    std::cout <<"Received unconverted message - manuak: "<< command.data << std::endl;

    if(checked == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Message received from correct callback - Manual" << std::endl;
        checked = false;
        thread_running=false;
    }
    else
    {
        checked = true;
    }
}
 void callback_auto(const std_msgs::String& command)
    {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("RECEIVED a callback");
        std::cout <<"Received unconverted message - auto: "<< command.data << std::endl;

        if(checked == true)
        {
            std::cout << "Message received from correct callback - Manual" << std::endl;
            checked = false;
            thread_running=false;
        }
        else
        {
            checked = true;
        }
    }

while(thread_running)
{
    loop_rate.sleep();
    if(!thread_running) break;
    if(mode == "manual")
    {   
        std_msgs::Int8 msg;
        std::bitset<4> msg_bit;
        msg_bit.set(3,1);
        msg_bit.set(2,1);
        msg_bit.set(1,1); 
        msg_bit.set(0,0);
        std::cout << "Sending message in manual mode!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Message being: "<< msg_bit << std::endl;
        msg.data = int(msg_bit.to_ulong());
        control_front_to_python.publish(msg);
    }
    if(mode == "auto")
    {
        std::cout << "Publishing message in auto" << std::endl;
        std_msgs::Int8 msg;
        msg.data = 8;
        control_cpp_to_python.publish(msg);
    }
    ros::spinOnce();
}
```

I guess this is as scraped as it can be.  I guess the issue must be due to me setting the thread_running to false inside the callback. I've currently fixed  it by the `checked` bool as a temporary fix.

Comment: Can you clarify re one/two messages? I would understand your question such that the python node publishes two messages on /status, you see both messages with `rostopic echo` but only the first one in your C++ node? -- if so, can you show your main loop in the C++ node?

Comment: No.. only one message is being sent from the python node, but the one being processed in the cpp part is the message is the message that was previously send.

Comment: Putting the code up could be problem, as it bit more involved than simple main loop.  I am running multiple threads, when a certain thread runs  will the callback functionality also be available.  The callback ends the processing by closing the thread that handles the message.  I suspecting that could be an issue, or be the cause.

Comment: I've currently fixed the problem toggling a pin such that i process the threads ends when 2 callback has occured.  But thats certainly not a pretty solid fix.

Comment: But if something was previously sent, something/somebody must have sent it ;-) Anyway, it really sounds like an issue with processing the queues - possibly the thread does only run once. Without a code sample to reproduce this, it is hard to pin down precisely.

Comment: I will try to make a mwe ..

Comment: I added a MWE example..  I hope this should  be a scraped version of what is happening. I guess the error is that I the call end the thread. Then again?

Comment: I would guess so - you get the first message, then the thread stops and you don't call spinOnce anymore. You should rethink your setup. Maybe use an ASyncSpinner so the queue processing is independent from your code.